# Show $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to show that following function is measurable:

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\dfrac{1}{x} , x \in \mathbb{R} /  {0} &  & \\ 
 c ,    x=0&  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
where $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

This is what I have done:

$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}\chi_{(-\infty, 0)} + \dfrac{1}{x}\chi_{(0,\infty)} + c\chi_{[0]}$

My intervals are $I_1=(-\infty,0)$, $I_2=(0,\infty)$, and $I_3=[0]$.

$B_k=B \cap I_k$ for $k \in$ {$1,2,3$}

Then, $x \in B_1$ iff $x\in I_1$ and $\dfrac{1}{x}<a$, i.e., $x\in (\dfrac{1}{a},0)\cap (-\infty,0)$ which implies that $x\in(\dfrac{1}{a},0)$ for $a<0$.

$x \in B_2$ iff $x\in I_2$ and $\dfrac{1}{x}<a$, i.e., $x\in (0,\dfrac{1}{a})\cap (0,\infty)$ which implies that $x\in(0,\dfrac{1}{a})$ for $a>0$.

Can somebody tell me is this correct?

P.S.I haven't done for $B_3$.

Comment: What is $B$? You introduce it without any definition. I assume it has something to do with $a$, that also appears without any explanation?

Comment: @PaulSinclair ${f(x)<a}$ by definition for a measurable function

Comment: There is no "$a$" or "$B$" as some official part of the definition of a measurable function. And $f(x) < a$ does not prove that $f$ is measurable. What you have given in your proof is accurate, but it proves nothing yet about measurability.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I meant the definition of pre-image of f and f's intervals where it is measurable.

Comment: What intervals where it is measurable? Your purpose is to show that it is measurable, and what you have so far doesn't come close. If you are asking if what you have given is true, then yes it is. But if you think you have shown measurability on $I_1$ and $I_2$, no you have not, even without the lack of definition of $a$ and $B$.

Comment: It is not clear how you are trying to approach the proof, nor what your starting point is. What is $B$? What is $a$? Typically one tries to show that the set $\{x | f(x) R \alpha \}$ is measurable, where $R$ is one of the usual order symbols. You need to have some cases that depend on the value of $c$, which appears nowhere in the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L_\alpha = \{x | f(x) < \alpha \}$.

If $\alpha >0$, then $L_\alpha = (-\infty,0) \cup ({1 \over \alpha}, \infty)$,
if $c \ge \alpha$ or $L_\alpha = (-\infty,0] \cup ({1 \over \alpha}, \infty)$
if $c< \alpha$.

If $\alpha =0$, then $L_\alpha = (-\infty,0) $,
if $c \ge \alpha$ or $L_\alpha = (-\infty,0]$
if $c< \alpha$.

If $\alpha<0$, then $L_\alpha = ({1 \over \alpha}, 0)$,
if $c \ge \alpha$ or $L_\alpha = ({1 \over \alpha}, 0]$
if $c< \alpha$.

In all cases $L_\alpha$ is measurable, hence $f$ is measurable.